# Text in absolute container wraps at the edge of parent

Tags: html, css

There is an absolutely positioned container that has a max-width. When this container is at the edge of its parent, the text inside starts wrapping before max width is reached. Is there any way to stop it from doing so without setting an exact width?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwwuhoj4/5/)

```
<div class="wrap">
   long text long text long text

   <div class="container">
       text wraps much earlier then 150px at the parent edge         
   </div>
</div>

.wrap {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
}
.container {
    border: 2px solid green;
    padding: 3px;
    max-width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 250px;
}
```

edit: width:inherit gives full width to all containers, even those much shorter then max-width

Comment: This is standard behaviour. Absolutely positioned elements collapse to the width of their content unless a width is specified. `width:inherit` combined with max-width would be ideal.

Comment: max-width:xx combined with width:inherit is same as width:xx, which defeats the purpose:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try inheriting the width...

```
.two  {   
    left: 250px;
    width: inherit;
}
```

UPDATED:

Different approach (hopefully satisfying) is to use media queries.

```
  @media all and (min-width: 150px) {
    .container.two {
        width: inherit;
    }
}
```

This means, that whenever an element with class `.two` reaches `min-width` of 150px, it will be given new properties.

http://jsfiddle.net/Holybreath/jwwuhoj4/6/

Comment: This works in fiddle, but doesn't work on my actual website o.O

Comment: Browser info? other classes might override width. change to `width: inherit !important;`

Comment: both latest chrome and ff. and nope, important doesn't work either :(

Comment: I don't know the details, and purpose of all this, but last resort is having `min-width` declared in `.container`... is this acceptable?

Comment: giving width to parent container makes with: inherit work, however
width: inherit simply sets width to max width, and containers with short text will still be large.

Comment: still no:)) if this css is used for all containers, they all get width: inherit
http://jsfiddle.net/jwwuhoj4/7/

Comment: so , try to set it to the one you need :) i updated.

Comment: I know this is old, but media queries don't work by tracking the width of elements, the work by tracking the width of the viewport. With that code, as long as your browser window (or probably the containing iframe on jsfiddle.net) has a width of at least 150px, elements matching .container.two will be affected by that code.